# how to Group by a new Select statement

Tags: sql

So this is my current situation.

I have a Table 'Test' with following attributes:

- Id
- PatientID (FK)
- Result
- Type

I need to count how many patients have done a test from a specific type (it's a 1 - * relationship between Patient and Test).

I solved it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Test 
WHERE (Type = 'GDS') 
GROUP BY PatientID;
```

And now I have to group those results.. ("How many Patients have done n tests")

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Test 
WHERE (Type = 'GDS') 
GROUP BY 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Test WHERE (Type = 'GDS') 
    GROUP BY PatientID
);
```

Of course it's wrong, since I don't have a clue how to do it .. and I couldn't find anything on the web.

It's a SQL database in Visual Studio ... so I'm not sure if JOINS are going to work.. and if, how would you use it?

Comment: Removed C# tag as it doesn't pertain to C#.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question:

> I need to Count how many How many patients have done a test from a
>   specific type (it's a 1 - * relationship between Patient and Test).

This is the solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PatientID) FROM Test WHERE Type = 'GDS'
```

For example, if you have:

```
ID | PatiantID | Type
1  | 71        | GDS
2  | 71        | FTP
3  | 53        | GDS
```

Then the code above will return `2`, coz there are two patients who had the GDS test.

Answer (score 3):

Is this homework?
You are searching for the [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause, that permits you to filter an aggregate result:

```
SELECT PatientID
FROM Test 
WHERE Type = 'GDS'
GROUP BY PatientID
HAVING COUNT(*) = n
```

Comment: Where `n` is a integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as PatientCount 
 FROM Test 
 WHERE Type = 'GDS'
```

or with GROUP BY

```
 SELECT PatientID, COUNT(*) as PatientCount FROM Test 
 WHERE Type = 'GDS'
 GROUP BY PatientID
```

And if you want specific number of the Aggregate function COUNT() you could use HAVING instead of WHERE, like:

```
 SELECT PatientID, COUNT(*) as PatientCount FROM Test 
 WHERE Type = 'GDS'
 GROUP BY PatientID
 HAVING COUNT(*) = n tests
```